# Django ORM does not refresh foreign key from saved object

Tags: python, django, orm

After updating a foreign key in a object, the related object does not refresh.

model.py:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey( 'NameStatus' )

class NameStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

testing it:

```
     >>> name_obj = Name.objects.exclude(name="Foo").get()
     >>> print ( status.status.id )
     2
     >>> name_obj.status_id = status.status.id + 1
     >>> print ( "%d vs %d" % (status.status.id, status.status_id )
     2 vs 3
```

Sample data:

Name:

```
| id | name | status (status_id) |
----------------------------------
| 1  | Foo  | 2                  |
| 2  | Bar  | 3                  |
```

Status:

```
| id | status        |
----------------------
| 1  | First Status  |
| 2  | Second Status |
| 3  | Third Status  |
```

What am I missing?

Should .get() be called again in a queryset up refresh the object?

I understand that this is probably to reduce unneeded calls to the database, but how to avoid this?

With this sample data, how do I move the foreign key from *Second Status* to *Third Status* in Django orm.

PS: As some answers below try to argue that a field_id attribute does not exist or that it would create a new object attribute.  This is not right.  It was tested under the debugger and save() does reflect it in the database.  The **_id** documentat reference is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

Edit: Change the status object to name to reflect the Class right.  Added sample data.

Comment: Why are you adding a new key status_id to name object(as there is no field defined in the model for the same)?

Comment: Because that's how Django named the status field in the Name table in the database: status_id.  Is that the wrong way (tm) to deal with it?

Comment: First of all there is problem with your naming convention of the objects.

Comment: edited to reflect the object name as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your test statements:

```
 >>> name_obj = Name.objects.exclude(name="Foo").get()
 >>> print ( name_obj.status.id )
 2
 >>> name_obj.status.id = name_obj.status.id + 1
 >>> print ( "%d vs %d" % (name_obj.status.id, name_obj.id)
```

Expected ans:  3 vs 2

Comment: name_obj.id and name_obj.status_id are different fields.

Comment: But in django orm this how you read foreign key. Don't get confused with actual db column. The above will work fine, just give it a try.

Comment: Added some sample data and renamed the object variable as you suggested to make it clear.

Comment: Its still not same as my answer. Follow the same as mine.

Comment: Done.  Still, name_obj.status.id and name_obj.id are different table's pk.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are doing two different things here.

- with status.status.id, you address the object's database id.
- with status.status_id, you create a new object property *status_id* 'on the fly' and assign the value 3 to it

The former is not related to the latter, so they can have different values

For example, you could do:

```
from .models import Name

status = Name.objects.exclude(name="Foo").get()
status.status.foo = 'bar'
```

The result will be as follows: status.status.foo will give you 'bar'.

Comment: Are you sure of that?  For what I understood, status.status.id is the pk of the status table and not the pk of the name table.  
With this logic the object's database id is just status.id.

Comment: Yes, status.status.id is the pk of the status table. status.status_id is a property of the Name object (which, in this example, is misleadingly also called status). It would be clearer if the object retrieve from the queryset (which is a Name object) would be called name. Then name.status.id gives you the id (pk) of the related status object, and name.status_id is a property defined on the fly on the name object.

Comment: Fixed the name.  About the _id, you are wrong: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

Comment: I checked it. And I still believe what I wrote is correct: you can use status_id to address the value, but not to assign it. Instead, I believe when assigning a value to name_obj.status_id, a new property on name_obj is created called status_id, and not on the related status obj. I replicated it and got the exact save result as you: name_obj.status.id gives me 2, whereas name_obj.status_id gives me 3.

Comment: I looked it up. I believe that when assinging a value to name_obj.status_id, we define a new instance attribute on the name_obj instance. This overrides the class attribute with the same name.

Comment: not true.  I tested id under the debugger.  Not that when calling save() it does save as expected in the database.